# Form action with variable not valid after update to 1.2

Tags: angularjs

I was generating a form action in my previous version of `AngularJS` using this code:

```
<form action="{{ api }}/products/image">
```

However, I just updated and now that apparently is too loose.

> Error while interpolating: {{ api }}/products/image
>   Strict Contextual Escaping disallows interpolations that concatenate multiple expressions when a trusted value is required.

How do I achieve the same functionality in `1.2.4`?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Since Angular 1.2.x, you can [bind only one expression as URL](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#you-can-only-bind-one-expression-to).

Hence, on your controller, do the following:

```js
$scope.actionUrl = $scope.api + '/products/image';
```

And in the template:

```
<form action="{{ actionUrl }}">
```

**Update**

As suggested by @Fourth:

```
<form action="{{ api + '/products/image' }}">
```

Comment: An alternative: `<form action="{{api + '/products/image'}}">`

Comment: This can cause a "Error: [$sce:insecurl] Blocked loading resource from url not allowed by $sceDelegate policy" error when the URL is on a different server.

Comment: @SarahVessels Good point. One would need to `$scope.actionUrl = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl($scope.actionUrl)` in that case, I think.

Comment: @musically_ut I got around it by doing `$sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist(['http://my-form-action/path', 'self'])`.

Comment: $sceDelegateProvider tip. This helped me with the unsafe concat error. Thank you!