# Interpolating inside form action attribute

Tags: forms, angularjs

I am trying to do something like this:

```
<form ng-controller='bulkCtrl' action='/bulk/{{ action }}'>
...
</form>
```

I get the error

> Error: [$interpolate:noconcat]

Pretty new to Angular...

What's wrong and how is it possible to achieve what I want ?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Form action with variable not valid after update to 1.2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20552395/form-action-with-variable-not-valid-after-update-to-1-2)

Comment: @camden_kid doesn't work :(

Comment: @nemesv this is indeed the same, didn't stumble on it when I was searching for answers

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any point to interpolate form's action. Just define [your action on scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit) and do what you want.