# AngularJS variables not binded inside form tag

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Im working with AngularJS and something really weird happens.

In the same HTML file I have the following two lines of code:

```
<img id ="image_displayed" src='{{rootContext}}/images/{{team.imgUrl}}' />
```

and

```
 <form  action='{{rootContext}}/images/{{team.imgUrl}}' method="POST">
```

I have defined rootContext in $rootScope as a global variable, $rootScope.rootContext = 'whatever'. The point is that in the image tag is binded correctly, but when it is inside the form tag, AngularJS makes no magic and then the value of the action attribute remains as "{{rootContext}}/images/{{team.imgUrl}}".

**Updated:**

The solution to this problem is to write it as follows:

```
<form id="joinTeamForm" action="{{ rootContext + '/images/' + team.imgUrl}}" method="POST">
```

Comment: Seems like the same issue you are having:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20552395/form-action-with-variable-not-valid-after-update-to-1-2

Comment: Definitely that link contains the solution to my problem. Thanks a lot.