# How to set the action of a form using angularjs controller variable?

Tags: angularjs

I have a form like this:

```
<form action="http://my-action-url">
...
</form>
```

How do I include use a variable to set the "action" url to be equivalent to say a variable in my controller:

```
$scope.actionURL = "http://my-action-url";
```

?

I am currently doing:

```
<form action="{{actionURL}}">
...
</form>
```

However, when I inspect element, i see the action tag is empty.

Comment: are you getting any console error ?

Comment: I'm not seeing any console errors. When I click on the submit button, it doesnt actually post to the url. When I inspect the specific form, I see action="" and does not populate with the expected string.

Comment: if you try to print your actionURL in a span does it work?  assign any other scope variables and print them in a span do they work?

Comment: I didn't find any error in your code. See this example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20552395/form-action-with-variable-not-valid-after-update-to-1-2

Comment: I saw that, but I notice that when I include http://, it does not work...

Answer (score 1):

here is the code available to set action in a form using an angularJs scope variable. i have successfully run this code. please check this.

Here Submit will not work because stackoverflow does not allow to submit. for more detail you can see this error in console

```js
 angular.module("test",[]).controller("testAction",testAction);
    function testAction($scope) {
    $scope.actionURL = "http://www.google.com";
    $scope.testD =  function() {
     location.href = $scope.actionURL;
    };
}
```

```html
 

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <script   src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js">
 </script>
</head>
<body ng-app="test">
 <div ng-controller="testAction">
   <form ng-submit="testD();">
     <input type="submit" >
     <div>{{actionURL}}</div>
   </form>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: My application is running at...http://home-url. When I try your answer, (using target="_blank", I see its trying to go to http://home-url/""http://www.google.com"", which does not seem correct.

Answer (score 1):

You may write the form with

```
$sce.trustAsHtml(html);
```

by yourself

Edit : better use

```
<form action="{{trustAction(your post url)}}">
```

and in your scope write

```
$scope.trustAction = function (actionURL) {
    return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(actionURL);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form
Angular prevent action and due to that you have to use 
ng-submit or ng-click
as http://dojo.telerik.com/EmEki

Answer (score 0):

I used jquery selector to set the form action.

```
<form method="post" name="deleteForm" action="#">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token('delete') }}">
    <md-button ng-click="closeDialog()" class="md-raised md-primary md-button md-ink-ripple">
        Cancel
    </md-button>
    <md-button type="submit" class="md-raised md-warn md-button md-ink-ripple">
        Delete
    </md-button>
</form>
```

And in my controller:

```
$('form[name="deleteForm"]').attr('action', '/manager/card-design/' + cardDesign.id);
```